# Flask/Werkzeug, how to return previous page after login

Tags: python, authentication, flask, werkzeug

I am using the Flask micro-framework which is based on Werkzeug, which uses Python.

Before each restricted page there is a decorator to ensure the user is logged in, currently returning them to the login page if they are not logged in, like so:

```
# Decorator
def logged_in(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not session['logged_in']:
                flash('Please log in first...', 'error')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            else:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            flash('Please log in first...', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return decorated_function


# Login function
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """Login page."""
    if request.method=='POST':
    ### Checks database, etc. ###
    return render_template('login.jinja2')


# Example 'restricted' page
@app.route('/download_file')
@logged_in
def download_file():
    """Function used to send files for download to user."""
    fileid = request.args.get('id', 0)
    ### ... ###
```

After logging in, it needs to return users to the page that took them to the login page.
It also needs to retain things such as the passed variables (i.e. the entire link basically www.example.com/download_file?id=3 )

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think standard practice is to append the URL to which the user needs to be redirected after a successful login to the end of the login URL's querystring.

You'd change your decorator to something like this (with redundancies in your decorator function also removed):

```
def logged_in(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('logged_in') is not None:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('Please log in first...', 'error')
            next_url = get_current_url() # However you do this in Flask
            login_url = '%s?next=%s' % (url_for('login'), next_url)
            return redirect(login_url)
    return decorated_function
```

You'll have to substitute something for `get_current_url()`, because I don't know how that's done in Flask.

Then, in your login handler, when the user successfully logs in, you check to see if there's a `next` parameter in the request and, if so, you redirect them to that URL.  Otherwise, you redirect them to some default URL (usually `/`, I guess).

Comment: +1 see also first link for a handy little feature of flask to do that else block

Comment: get_current_url() is flask.request.url

Answer (score 12):

You could use a query string to keep the file info intact over a click or two.  One of the nice things about `url_for` is how it [passes unknown parameters as query strings](http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2010/4/26/implementing-list-with-sort-filter/#ac19ff7d428cd21b5013c978bad4c30e).  So without changing your registration page too much you could do something like this:

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('register', wantsurl = request.path))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Here `wantsurl` will keep track of the url the user landed on.  If an unregistered user goes to `/download/some/file.txt`, `login_required` will send you to `/register?wantsurl=%2Fdownload%2Fsome%2Ffile.txt`  Then you add a couple of lines to your registration function:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'wantsurl' in request.args:
            qs = request.args['wantsurl']
            return render_template('register.html', wantsurl=qs)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'wantsurl' in request.form and everything_else_ok:
            return redirect(request.form['wantsurl'])
```

That would automatically redirect to the download on successful registration, provided you have something in the form called 'wantsurl' with the value of `qs`, or you could have your form submit with a query string; that could just be a little if-else in the template.