# Flask how to redirect to previous page after successful login

Tags: flask

I have a webapp where I don't use Flask-login. If user visit a link and is not logged in, I redirect the user to login page. I achieve this my setting 'username' in session and checking that when user tries to access some link directly without logging in i.e in that case username will be null.

I have tried to follow this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686465/flask-werkzeug-how-to-return-previous-page-after-login), but the next parameter is always None. I have tried both solution but can't get either one to work.

```
username = session.get('username')
if username:
    # go to home 
else:
    next_url = request.url
    login_url = '%s?next=%s' % (url_for('login'), next_url)
    return redirect(login_url)
```

Second solution

```
username = session.get('username')
if username:
    # go to home 
else:
    return redirect(url_for('login', next= request.url))
```

print (request.url) = localhost:5000/visitPage

Login Function

```
   if 'next' in request.args:
     return redirect(next)
   else:
     return redirect(url_for("user.index"))
```

Here when I  print (next), it is None 
But login url has next argument

> http://localhost:5000/login?next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2FvisitPage

Comment: Put here print out of request.url from the second solutions. If it None, `url_for`  skips it and not passes as a query param

Comment: I have included the print. It is None but request.url before the request and url itself has next, so why it is Null ? Is there something wrong in how I'm checking for next ?

Comment: is you login function handler accepts GET or POST methods? If it is POST you should check request.form.get('next')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be several problems:

- `url_for` skips query param if it has None value
- your login endpoint takes `POST` requests. In such case you have to get the `next` param such way `request.form.get('next')`

If these tips do not help you, you can put `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` (may be you have to install `ipdb` first) in your code and try to debug it for better understanding what is going on here or put more context for understanding your problem.

Comment: Issue was in Login function. Login func does form validation and redirected the user if form data is invalid. So, in this case first call to login function resulted in re-direct and the next data was gone on second request. Had to save the next data between the two request and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 16):

Use session to keep track of the previous url,
for example:

```
@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
    if user_not_logged_in:
        session['url'] = url_for('profile')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return rendertemplate('profile.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    if login == True: #assuming login was successful
         if 'url' in session:
            return redirect(session['url'])
         return redirect(url_for('anyother_url'))
```

Comment: Slight improvement: Using `return redirect(session.pop('url', None))` for the redirect after login will clear the session variable directly, so you don't have to worry about unwanted redirects at a later point.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way I use

Add a **hidden** input

```
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{request.args.get('next')}}" />
```

and in your **app.py**

```
    return redirect(request.form.get('next'))
```