# Flask logging in issue

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask to develop a login interface. Once the user has logged in, the page should redirect to the dashboard. Instead I get the message, `You are now logged in` and `Unauthorized user`. The code does not redirect to the dashboard.

I have the following code-

```
def is_logged_in(f): #Check if user logged in
@wraps(f)
def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        flash('Unauthorized user', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
return wrap

#Dashboard
@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
  return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

Please help me understand why the decorator is not behaving like it should.

Comment: I don't see where you're logging "You are now logged in" at all

Comment: It is in another function which redirects to `dashboard`. The issue is between `dashboard` and `is_logged_in`.

Comment: The current logic tells "redirect to `login` page if unathorized user visites `dashboard`" but you are expecting reverse. this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686465/flask-werkzeug-how-to-return-previous-page-after-login

Comment: No, the logic is correct. The code logic is like this `login`->`dashboard`->`is_logged_in`. The code does not recognize that the user has logged in even though the correct message appears.

Answer (score 0):

I did not initialize session details due to which the `username` was not logged. I added the following lines in the `login` function and the errors were resolved-

```
session['logged_in'] = True
session['username'] = username
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        flash('Unauthorized user', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap
```